# Accessing shared folders

Tags: networking, network-shares

I have shared a folder in a remote PC....when I access the folder through run (\192.168.4.*) it doesn't ask for credentials the 2nd time (Without mapping the folder). How can I have the credential window popping up when ever I want?

Comment: Much more info is required : What are the two involved operating systems, share permissions and owner, method of accessing the shares.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage saved credentials in the `Control Panel` at `User Accounts` -> `Manage your passwords`.

At least on Vista, you can access the dialog with:

```
rundll32 keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

Alternatively, you can log off using:

```
net use \\<path to network share> /DELETE
```

Sources:

- [Windows 7 Help: Remove stored passwords, certificates, and other credentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Remove-stored-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials)
- [en.kioskea.net: To disable auto login network share folders](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-35879-to-disable-auto-login-network-share-folders)